# What is my room?

Tags: calculation-puzzle

You are heading to your hotel room but forget your room number. 
Try to check the key card but the digits are blurred 
You call to hotel desk info and a nerdy bell boy tell you:

- Your room have 4 digits
- the digits are different
- the digits are in an increasing order
- the product of the first two is the sum of the last two.

What is your room number?

Comment: Also I found three possible answers...

Comment: My bad, i only found one when made it.

Comment: Perhaps this hotel only has 3568 rooms.

Comment: @Ayefork Or only 34 floors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The room number is **3457**, **3569**, or **3578**. 3 × 4 = 5 + 7, and 3 × 5 = 6 + 9 or 7 + 8.

Answer (score 0):

The answers are 3457,3569 & 3578. Calculated using brute force:
http://ideone.com/yD3RXL

Comment: That's a rather inefficient piece of code, though it does the job in this case.